# In the new Firebase console I can't edit the name of nor move nor clone any node of a realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

In the new Firebase console I can't edit the name of nor clone nor move any node (change parent) of a realtime database

I have even tested setting Rules to Public.

Is this by design ? What then, is the use of this console ? ONLY to change child values ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is indeed no way to clone a node or rename a key in the Firebase Database console. Since the Firebase Database API doesn't have a clone/rename operation, we also don't have an equivalent in the UI.

Note that this operation also wasn't possible in the previous Firebase Dashboard, for the same reason. It has nothing to do with your security rules nor with the new release.

If you want to move a node to a new location, you'll have to emulate it:

1. Go to the [Database tab in your Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data)
2. Navigate your JSON tree until you've selected the node that you want to move
3. Open the overflow menu (three vertical dots: <kbd>⋮</kbd>) on the right and select <kbd>Export JSON</kbd>. Save the file to your local disk.
4. Delete the node from the JSON tree
5. Navigate your JSON tree to the location where you want to move the data
6. Open the overflow menu (three vertical dots: <kbd>⋮</kbd>) on the right and select <kbd>Import JSON</kbd>. Select the file from your local disk.

Comment: yeah the 'new release' wasn't intended I had copied it from another post :)

I thought I had seen code wherein to rename a node one would copy a node (clone) and delete (remove) old one via APIs ? Am I mistaken ?

Comment: nevermind, I see now that is a manual js copy (could not edit my comment)

Comment: Hope things like this get added soon. The Firebase web interface at the moment is functional but rudimentary.

Comment: Could not agree more with Venryx. This almost makes thigns unworkable once you are deep in a project and need to change anything.

Comment: 'Navigate your JSON tree': has this changed? I can't see how to do it from the console. (BTW for export, this looks useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firestore-import-export.)

Comment: Nope, nothing has changed there recently as far as I know. Just click on the <kbd>+</kbd> to open nodes and then on a node name to focus the tree on that specific node.

Comment: Indeed, this answer is out of date. The three dots no longer include an option to export to JSON.

Comment: I just checked and the `Export JSON` option still shows up for me. Are you sure you're looking at he console for the **Realtime Database** (which has this option) and not for Cloud Firestore (which indeed does not have this option)?