# Changing/Moving data on Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I'm new on firebase and i'm using the console.firebase to insert some data for testing the integration on my apps. I would like to know if there's a way on console to:

- Change de node name
- Move data

That`s part of my tree structure:

[image]

So, i want, for example, change Peru to Canada and move the Participants data from Travel agency committe to the Aviation committe. Can i do this using the console?

Comment: There is no way to move data within the Firebase Database API, nor is there a way to move it in the console. The best you can do is make a copy of the data in its new spot and then delete the original. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997242/in-the-new-firebase-console-i-cant-edit-the-name-of-nor-move-nor-clone-any-node/38999826#38999826

Comment: Okay, but how i can do this data copy on console? or i have to write everything again?

Comment: You can select the node, then click the overflow menu on the right (the three vertical dots) and then select Export JSON. Then go to the new location and select `Import JSON` from the same menu.

Comment: Very nice,Thank you!