# Firebase resetting the key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase as follow:

```
Post--

    -Kwc6asRRI1SUqrigYeD                 <- First input
                       -> Date: 1:00pm
                       -> ID: 1
                       -> Content: Hello!
    -Kwc6fXQsN2xIQtHOofZ  
                       -> Date: 2:00pm
                       -> ID: 2
                       -> Content: How are you?
    -Kwc6fXQsN2xRO39LDPD                  <-Most recent one
                       -> Date: 3:00pm
                       -> ID: 3
                       -> Content: I am good.
```

These are "pushed" thus an unique key is generated which can be used to display them according to the `"most recent to old"` (or `ID:3` to `ID:1`).

**Now**, when I need to update a data, let say `ID:1` post's content from `"Hello"` to `"My name is Steve"`, then it still maintains the unique key even though this is the most recent one.

```
Post--

    -Kwc6asRRI1SUqrigYeD                 <-Most recent one
                       -> Date: 4:00pm
                       -> ID: 1
                       -> Content: My name is Steve
    -Kwc6fXQsN2xIQtHOofZ  
                       -> Date: 2:00pm
                       -> ID: 2
                       -> Content: How are you?
    -Kwc6fXQsN2xRO39LDPD                  
                       -> Date: 3:00pm
                       -> ID: 3
                       -> Content: I am good.
```

I guess I can delete the post and set a new one, but that seems inefficient especially if I have more data on each child.

Is there a way to re-set the key so that it reflects the time change (like below)?

```
Post--

    -Kwc6fXQsN2xIQtHOofZ  
                       -> Date: 2:00pm
                       -> ID: 2
                       -> Content: How are you?
    -Kwc6fXQsN2xRO39LDPD                  
                       -> Date: 3:00pm
                       -> ID: 3
                       -> Content: I am good.

    -Kwc6asRRI1KDodkeixk                <-Most recent one
                       -> Date: 4:00pm
                       -> ID: 1
                       -> Content: My name is Steve
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to update the key of an existing node (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997242/in-the-new-firebase-console-i-cant-edit-the-name-of-nor-move-nor-clone-any-node), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456443/how-to-move-firebase-child-from-one-node-to-another-in-android), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107274/is-it-possible-to-rename-a-key-in-the-firebase-realtime-database)). If you want a new key, you'll have to generate a new node with the same content.

But in this case it seems much more likely that you want to keep your data structure as is and instead add a `lastUpdated` timestamp to each post:

```
Post--
    -Kwc6asRRI1SUqrigYeD
                   -> Date: 1:00pm
                   -> lastUpdated: 1508215054096
                   -> ID: 1
                   -> Content: Hello!
    -Kwc6fXQsN2xIQtHOofZ  
                   -> Date: 2:00pm
                   -> lastUpdated: 1507610306270
                   -> ID: 2
                   -> Content: How are you?
    -Kwc6fXQsN2xRO39LDPD
                   -> Date: 3:00pm
                   -> lastUpdated: 1508128668412
                   -> ID: 3
                   -> Content: I am good.
```

With this structure you can use a Firebase query to get the results in the order you want. In JavaScript this would look something like:

```js
var ref = firebase.database().reference("Post");
ref.orderByChild("lastUpdated")
   .once("value")
   .then(function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(post) {
       console.log(snapshot.key+": "+snapshot.val().Content);
     });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks Frank! Much appreciated.